# Google Sign in occasional ApiException: 4: 4:

Tags: android, google-signin, google-authentication

I've recently implemented Sign in with Google (Google Auth) in the application, following the official documentation. Regardless of whether it's a silent sign in or a normal one, **sometimes** it doesn't work and I'm getting this error log:

```
2021-12-23 01:20:14.179 4952-4952/ee.myapp.client.debug E/[main] -> Services - Auth: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4: 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.6.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zap.onComplete(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.6.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.6.0:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.6.0:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zbf.zbd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.2.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zbq.zba(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.2.0:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.2.0:3)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1179)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1143)
```

I cannot test on the published version yet, this is the debug build, which acts weird, because 95% of time everything works just fine, and only 5% I'm getting this error, and I'm getting it repeadedly. Looks like Google stops giving my user access to the app for some reason.